# Vertices of the 57 cell Perkel graph

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, polyhedra

Im looking for the vertices of the Perkel graph. I've seen somewhere that the vertex set is $Z_3\times Z_{19}$. What does that mean ? Indeed $3 \times 19 = 57$ but the vertices should be 4-dimensional. I'm a bit ignorant in geometry.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Graphs don't have canonical coordinates. You mention $4$ dimensions, are you asking about the vertices of the $57$-cell, whose vertices and edges form the Perkel graph?

Comment: @JoshB. Yes, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: There was an attempt to find nice coordinates for the $57$-cell, but it looks unsuccessful. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896614/the-57-cell-in-5d-or-4d

Comment: @JoshB.: That was *my* unsuccessful attempt! :) I'll reiterate the key point: *A matrix whose rows are eigenvectors of a graph's adjacency matrix has columns that serve as coords of a realization for which each graph automorphism is induced by an isometry.* Arguably, this gives a canonical *shape* for a graph realization (well, *shapes*: one for each eigenvalue), even if the generated coords are a mess. Anyway, it's a place to start. One could perhaps use knowledge of a graph's automorphisms to rotate the realization to have convenient axes or planes of symmetry, maximizing coord nice-ness.